# How do I make the underline (of a text in a table) another color in a Reporting Services report?

Tags: html, reporting-services, underline

I want to make the underline of entries in a table another color than the actual text (simply because it looks better). As stated in the header, how do I make the underline (of a text in a table) another color (compared to the text itself) in a Reporting Services report? I am working through visual studio 2010.

I haven't found the option in the properties pane (and a web search seemed to confirm this). I also played around a little with the Placeholders ability to interpret HTML which might be a way to do it, but I never got it to work (but I know only very basic HTML, so I was on kinda deep water there.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing underline color with css doesn't work in chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289248/changing-underline-color-with-css-doesnt-work-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

You can make some HTML like that

http://jsfiddle.net/JEGqy/1/

Underline is like a border-bottom. I never do web code with VS2010, but you can do like that

Comment: I actually tried to enter something like that to the expression of the textbox (after having placed a placeholder and ticked "Interpret html-tags as styles"). I wrote it like this: _="<span style="border-bottom: 2px solid green;">foo</span>"_ but then had the (quite obvious) problem that the expression editor didn't understand that the quotation marks were supposed to be nested. Any ideas on this?

Comment: the better way is to make your css by class. 
Why are you using VS2010 ? is it a ASP.NET project ? You can try to add the span tag by the code, it's look better

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is possible to change the underline color .But you can use `border` properties of the textbox and change the colour .Refer [this MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281379%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article

Comment: May be this can help you .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322088/expression-to-change-specific-value-text-color-in-string-of-values-in-ssrs-based

Answer (score 0):

You should use nested tags

the outer tag gets a color and will be unterlined. The inner tag gets a different color and will not be underlined

http://jsfiddle.net/238gw/2/

```
<span><span>Text</span></span>​
```

---

```
span {color: blue; text-decoration: underline;}
span > span {color: red; text-decoration: none;}​
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have written that I am quite new to Reporting Services as well (I have worked with it for 9 weeks). How exactly would I insert this into the report?

Comment: I don't know anything about reporting services. I can help you with the CSS part. You should search for how to add custom templates/themes/skin etc to reporting services